# Git post receive hook on a different computer

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I've got my website set up so that when I'm done working locally and testing etc, I can push changes live like so:

`git push khwp`

This works great. And my local files are in a Dropbox folder so I can work on them on my laptop too. On the latter however, the aforementioned command does not work. I can add and commit files just fine, but for some reason the push command does not work.

How can I fix this?

I should probably add that I'm new to git, but I guess you figured that out...

**EDIT:** this is the error I'm getting :

```
/bin/bash: line 0: exec: socat: not found
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

No corporate firewall, no "push url". The keys are configured without a problem (I can ssh into the server without password) and username and email are set too.

Comment: What error message are you getting? Does `git remote show origin` return anything on the laptop?

Comment: What do you get for "Push URL" when you issue `git remote show origin`? Did you configure a public rsa key on your Desktop, but neglect to do so on your laptop? Have you configured your laptop's `~/.gitconfig` to have a user.name and user.email?

Comment: ... and are you attempting to push to a git repository that lives behind a (corporate?) firewall, and forgetting to VPN or otherwise tunnel in? That's the error that I get when I'm trying to push from home and forget to launch my VPN client.

Comment: what does this have to do with "post receive hook" that's in the subject? what does your hook do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I look around at Google searching for `socat git`, I [find](http://www.emilsit.net/blog/archives/how-to-use-the-git-protocol-through-a-http-connect-proxy/) that `socat` is used in order to tunnel the `git://` protocol through `https`. The referenced post recommends to create a `gitproxy` script and use this script as global proxy script:

```
$ git config --global core.gitproxy gitproxy
```

I assume you *somehow* configured Git to use `socat` and it's simply not installed on your laptop computer.

Comment: Ok so the problem was there was a proxy configured in ~/.ssh/ssh_config. I removed everything in there and it FINALLY work. Grepping for socat provided me with the name of the file to look into, thank you.